構造体のメンバ変数が参照できない
PaintCircle関数内の11行目の
*(img.data + x * img.Ny + y) = g;

で「クラスimageにメンバー"data"がありません。」というエラーが出てきます。
どうすれば、参照できるでしょうか？

（宿題の条件としてmain関数内は変えない。というものがあります。またimage構造体の中身を画像で貼っておきます）
chatgptに聞いて、関数内の引数をImage *imgとすれば、Image 構造体へのポインターを受け取り、元の構造体のメンバーにアクセスできるようになります。と帰ってきましたが、解決しませんでした。
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    "cglec.h"

void PaintCircle(Image img, int x0, int y0, int r, int g)
{
    int x, y;
  
   //この円を描くフィールドのアドレスを表すアドレスはimgのdata
    for (x = x0 - r; x < x0 + r; x++)
    {
        for (y = y0 - r; y < y0 + r; y++)
        {
            if ((x - x0) * (x - x0) + (y - y0) * (y - y0) <= r * r)
                *(img.data + x * img.Ny + y) = g;
           
        }
    }

// この関数を作成する． x0,y0 : 中心座標， r : 半径，g : グレーレベル
}

int main(void)
{
    int Nx, Ny;
    printf("画像の横方向ピクセル数は？ ");  scanf("%d", &Nx);
    printf("画像の縦方向ピクセル数は？ ");  scanf("%d", &Ny);
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * Nx * Ny);
    if (data == NULL)                           //メモリ割当成功か？
    {
        printf("メモリエラー!!"); exit(0);
    } //メモリ割当に失敗したらプログラムを終了する
    Image img = {data, Nx, Ny };
    CglSetAll(img, 0);
    PaintCircle(img, Nx / 2, Ny / 2, Nx / 5, 255);
    PaintCircle(img, 0, 0, Nx / 8, 150);
    PaintCircle(img, Nx / 2, Ny / 8, Nx / 6, 100);
    PaintCircle(img, 5 * Nx / 4, 3 * Ny / 4, Nx / 2, 50);
    PaintCircle(img, Nx / 2, 7 * Ny / 4, Nx, 200);
    CglSaveGrayBMP(img, "Circles.bmp");
    free(data);        //メモリ解放
}


C/C++言語のシンボルは、大文字/小文字が区別されます。

前のコメントで「大文字/小文字が区別されます」というのは、構造体メンバーの定義がunsigned char* Data;として最初のDが大文字で定義されているのに、ソースコードではimg.dataとしてdが小文字で書かれていることを指しています。
